# Paginated XML parsing from API

Tags: python, api, elementtree

I have a snippet of code that calls a request to an API and retrieves XML data. The API limits requests to 50 results per page. I can loop through the pages but they always return an end to the root (Interactions) for the page:

```
     <interactions>
     <interaction>
     <media-type>Phone</media-type>
     <channel-obj-id>12125000870</channel-obj-id>
     </interaction>
     </interactions>
     <interactions>
     <interaction>
     <media-type>Phone</media-type>
     <channel-obj-id>523452345</channel-obj-id>
     </interaction>
     </interactions>
```

I have looped through the record count to get all the data but it does not provide it as a continuous XML page.

The API docs does not provide any relevant information nor provide a count or total number of pages parameter.

```
    dt = datetime.today() - timedelta(days =1)
    dt = dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')

    while rootLength == 50:
        n+=50
        response = (requests.get('https://APIURL/api/stats/allinteractions? 
        d=20190101,'+str(dt)+'&n='+str(n),
                    auth=('user','pass')
                    ))

        xtree = et.ElementTree(et.fromstring(response.content))
```

Is there a way to retrieve a single continuous XML page?

Comment: Likely there isn't - the API has to return each page as a complete valid self-contained XML, so you will have to reassemble them.

Comment: @barny Reassemble as in remove the other end-root tags until it seems continuous?

Comment: Yes, assuming what you show is the exact XML you are receiving. Actually what you show isn’t well-formed, is there another tag around it all?

Comment: No, the first element is "interactions" - what make it's form not good?

Comment: Because there isn’t an overall surrounding tag, so as it stands it’s not valid XML. Try pasting it into e.g. Notepad++ and use the plugin XML Tools - it will validate the xml. Is that really what you’re getting for each page?

Comment: <Interactions/> is the overall surrounding tag. The issue is that when running through the loop it terminates the tag and then opens another when it is a new page.

Comment: But you show in the middle </interactions><interactions> which I hadn’t spotted when I made my first comment. Confused. Anyway basically you need to get all the <interaction>...</interaction> tags and combine them into one result